# SQL Left Join Insert not working

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, phpmyadmin, left-join

I am wanting to get the `entity_id` value from each row in the `catalog_product_entity` table, and each `store_id` value from each row in the `catalog_product_entity_int` table, where the `entity_id` of the first table is equal to the `entity_id` of the second table.

What is wrong with this SQL insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` ("","4","231",i.store_id,p.entity_id,"D")
SELECT p.entity_id, i.store_id
                FROM catalog_product_entity p
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int i 
                ON i.entity_id = p.entity_id;
```

**MySQL said:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"","4","231",i.store_id,p.entity_id,"D")
SELECT p.entity_id, i.store_id
                FR' at line 1
```

Comment: it should be like this . INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar 
SELECT '',4, 231,  i.store_id, p.entity_id, 'D'
                FROM catalog_product_entity p
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int i 
                ON i.entity_id = p.entity_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused two types of insert statements.

If you are trying to select the values from one table to insert it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
     (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6)
SELECT "","4","231",i.store_id,p.entity_id,"D"
                FROM catalog_product_entity p
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int i 
                ON i.entity_id = p.entity_id;
```

Add the hardcoded portion of the values to the select statement and specify which fields they are going into in the insert.

Read up on insert select statements from the [mysql doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to specify the fileds on an insert on select statment.

you're query should be something like

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
SELECT p.entity_id, i.store_id  --ADD MORE FIELDS HERE TO MATCH YOUR TARGET TABLE SCHEMA
                FROM catalog_product_entity p
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int i 
                ON i.entity_id = p.entity_id;
```

Notice that I dropped the `("","4","231",i.store_id,p.entity_id,"D")`

You'll want to add all the fields in the `SELECT` statement that are required for an insert into your targettable